# Using regex for parse n - arguments in System input

Tags: java, regex, file

I have to parse System input text using space(`\s`) and line (`\n`) as delimiters for logic.

Is it possible to improve code with a match for 1 to n-arguments?

Because I don't know in the beginning how much arguments will be.
`t` - parameter is a number of test cases.

Arguments could be *numbers, string or char symbols*.

For every test, there is limited time run - I have to use *the fastest algorithm* as possible to parse text.

```
3  //3 test cases
0 2
1 3 1
2 0 1 5
1  //1 test
0
2  //2 test
1 1 1 1
4 3 2 5 aaa 5 a 5 h 5 5 c 5 5 h 5 5 5 j 5 5 55 0 5 5 k 5 555 5
```

Here is an example with 2 `int` arguments:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.*;


public class Solution {

      public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)));
        int t = in.nextInt(); // Scanner has functions to read ints.
        for (int i = 1; i <= t; ++i) {
          int n = in.nextInt();
          int m = in.nextInt();
           System.out.println("Line #"+t+": "+n+ ", " + m); //calculate arguments by some logic

        }
      }
}
```

Comment: Use `in.nextLine()` and `line.split("\\s+")` to get an array with all the numbers in that line

Comment: I don't think you need regex for that? Read the text file line by line. Once you have read the first line, count each line for the number of test cases to get each test case then if you need the integers, split each test case on space.

Comment: I'd also suggest the approach from the other comments, but a RegEx could still be useful for a safer "parse". Something like `[^0-9]+` (faster) or even `\\D+` (prettier) as a splitting delimiter would ensure you only get numbers out.

Comment: How do you want to distinguish a string of digits from a number, a string of length one from a character?

Comment: For calculation I will use just numbers - but user input can contain everything  - I have to filter out rest of it